# How to get total, min and max values from category

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a custom visual for Power BI.

Using these capabilities categories and values are accepted:

```js
dataRoles: [
    {
        name: 'Category',
        kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Grouping,
    },
    {
        name: 'Values',
        kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Measure,
    }],
dataViewMappings: [{
    categorical: {
        categories: {
            for: { in: 'Category' },
            dataReductionAlgorithm: { top: {} }
        },
        values: {
            select: [{ bind: { to: 'Values' } }]
        },
    }
}],
```

Using `dataView.categorical.values[0].values` I am able to access the values of the first measure. However, `dataView.categorical.values[0].subtotal`, `.min` and `.max` are not set.

Min and max values can be determined using `D3.Base.min/max` but not the total values. How can I get those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categorical data views don't provide you with subtotals. To get subtotals, you need to use a [Table data view](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/14498d3899f17eac1ca7454d95385aa1fb7ba750/src/Clients/Visuals/capabilities/table.capabilities.ts) or a [Matrix data view](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/14498d3899f17eac1ca7454d95385aa1fb7ba750/src/Clients/Visuals/capabilities/matrix.capabilities.ts). Table data views give you row subtotals only. Matrix data views give you row and column subtotals.

Comment: Thanks, Lukasz, that answers the question. I'll switch to using a Matrix data view.

Comment: I am struggling to read the subtotals from the Matrix data view and have posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013533/accessing-subtotals-in-dataview-matrix. Would appreciate if you could have a look.